# when using expo-image-picker to take picture, expo client app crashes and reload after taking picture

Tags: react-native, crash, expo

when working with expo-image-picker, expo client app on my android phone crashes after taking picture.
[after clicking on done symbol the app reloads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF30c.jpg)

here is my code:

```
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
 const takeImageHandler = async () => {
    const hasPermission = await verifyPermissions();
    if (!hasPermission) {
      return;
    }
    const image = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [16, 9],
      quality: 0.5,
    });
    console.log(image);
  };
```

Comment: Did you fix it? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Just try using this code

```
const openCamera = async () => {
// Ask the user for the permission to access the camera
const permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();

if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
  alert("You've refused to allow this appp to access your camera!");
  return;
}

const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync();

// Explore the result
console.log(result);

if (!result.cancelled) {
  setPickedImagePath(result.uri);
  console.log(result.uri);
}
```

}

And make sure you have installed image picker using npm latest version
Must check your package.json again that expo image picker is installed or not

Comment: it works fine on some androids, as I checked it on my other phone. But on some mobiles, it reloads the app again. I think I should use Camera package instead of image picker package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while working with the expo-image-picker library today. I was able to open the camera and take the image but as soon as i tried to save the image by clicking the tick mark, the app reloaded. So, i tested it on my another phone and it worked perfectly.

The first phone that i was testing on was on old android phone and the second one was a newer android, so i suggest you use a newer/latest model.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).